# CSS file from GitHub pages sent as text/plain, needs to be text/css

Tags: github, css

I have a GitHub project with a CSS file and I want a HTML page to be able to pull this in so I created a GitHub pages branch and synced everything over.

The file is included as such:

```
<link href="https://raw.github.com/dublintech/JavaScript_Examples/gh-pages/jsquiz/css/jquiz.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But in Firebug I am getting the following error:

> The stylesheet `https://raw.github.com/dublintech/JavaScript_Examples/gh-pages/jsquiz/css/jquiz.css` was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/plain", is not "text/css".

So I still get wrong MIME type. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

This is by design as you should not be serving or linking to raw files in this manner.

It could also be [seen as abuse of their services](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-docs-alpha/issues/95#issuecomment-3630328) as linking to the raw file is using GitHub as a content delivery network (CDN).

Instead, you need to make use of the [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com/) feature and link to the file from there. Which, when you build your pages will be along the lines of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://repo-owner.github.com/repo/css/style.css">
```

In your case, it would be here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dublintech.github.com/JavaScript_Examples/jsquiz/css/jquiz.css">
```

And when it is referenced from the correct location, it will be served as `text/css` as expected/wanted.

Comment: This is a better way as it does prevent link rotting, though you have to manually update it if the original copy is changed on the master branch on the repository.

Comment: Another option is to just get rid of the master and work solely from the gh-pages branch - http://oli.jp/2011/github-pages-workflow/

Comment: it is github.io rather than github.com no?